# How can I organize complex queries?

Tags: mysql

I am analysing a relatively large (25GB compressed MySQL dump) static data set.  Some of the queries I'm writing are several tens of lines long, which makes them difficult to understand, modify, and reuse.  Also many query parts are reused in multiple queries.

I would like to break the processing into smaller parts, so that I can individually write and debug each part and reuse its results in other queries further down the road.  I could break the processing into views, but this would mean that each view would be evaluated multiple times (MySQL doesn't offer materialized views) making later queries very slow.  Alternatively, I could create intermediate tables (and suitable indices).  However, this would force me every time I modify a query, to find and recreate tables that depend on its results; a time-consuming and error-prone process.

I am thinking of automating and managing my workflow with [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29).  I would write one SQL query to create or recreate a table with its results (and suitable indices) in a separate file.  A *make* rule would create a dummy file every time the query gets evaluated, thus creating a timestamp, which will be used to determine which queries need to be executed or re-executed.  Dependencies between tables would be recorded in the Makefile, ensuring that all dependent tables get correctly updated.  Dependencies could be even automatically extracted from the queries by looking at the right of (suitably formatted) FROM and JOIN keywords.  This approach would provide me with modularity (one small query per file) and time efficiency (only the minimal set of queries will get evaluated when I change something).  Note that space is currently not a concern in my setup.

Given that the problem I'm facing must be fairly common, I wonder whether I'm missing another established solution.  I've read the [How to Eat a SQL Elephant in 10 Bites](http://spaghettidba.com/2012/03/15/how-to-eat-a-sql-elephant/) blog post, and I've also searched for similar questions here, but I can't say I've found something that addresses my requirements and concerns.

Comment: Could you please explain this argument: `I could break the processing into views, but this would mean that each view would be evaluated multiple times…`? Currently you have query parts that are re-used in multiple queries. If the re-used parts can be declared as views (so that the repeated parts are referenced just by a name instead of being wholly duplicated), how would that make things worse than they are currently? Or what did you mean by "break the processing into views"?

Comment: This is still work in progress, so there isn't a "current" implementation that I'm trying to improve.  Rather I'm trying to design a modular and efficient workflow. If I were to use a view in multiple queries, then each query would evaluate the view again, wasting time.